# CSS code priority

Tags: css

I want to load a css code from a specific stylesheet first, 
Like:

```
ul, ol {
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

the above code is in two files: `core.css` and `bootstrap.css`

`core.css` load first in head tag.

But browser always use code first from `bootstrap.css`.

I tried to rename `bootstrap.css` to `z-bootstrap.css`.
But no luck still browser apply styles from  `z-bootstrap.css`
It work when I edit `ul, ol` to `body ul, body ol` in `core.css`

But I dont want to do this, How to apply styles from `core.css` without adding any class or attribute.???

Comment: [Sounds like you need to learn about *the cascade*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your declaration, have `core.css` below/after `bootstrap.css`

example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core.css">
```

Comment: yeah.. You need to move it below bootstrap.

Comment: I am not a beginner, much expert in CSS. working more the 6 years on CSS. But I always think that loading css file at top will override other.... I learned this when i am a beginner. Now I realized my mistake

Answer (score 2):

The order of css application does not always depend on the include order, but on the level of specificity:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 1):

You need to load `core.css` after `bootstrap.css` in order for the rules in `core` to override `bootstrap`.

Comment: You are right chrisBrown, Whole time i am trying to add core above bootstrap

Comment: I just love him too much, My hands automatically typed it. Anyway thanks for the answer

Answer (score -3):

Try to put `!important` at the end

```
ul, ol {
margin: 0 0 10px 25px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
```

}

That will give priority

Comment: `!important` is using a sledgehammer where a normal one would do.

Comment: using `!important` should always be a last resort, never you first solution! definitely not in this case, where the solution is very simple. You will regret this later on!